# How to reset <div> back to pre-AJAX response state, after search field is cleared?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, perl

I have an HTML page that lists "all" data from a database.  I have included a search field that allows the user to search for a specific "line", via a Perl/AJAX process.  It works wonderfully.  The user inputs information, and the div that holds the original list is overwritten with the results of the AJAX request.  As long as they keep changing the information in the search field, the AJAX process continues to fire, and everything works well.  The problem comes in when they try to return to the original "all" list by clearing everything from the search field, rather than simply reloading the page.  This led me to wonder if it's possible to force a div to revert to it's original state (before it was overwritten by the AJAX response)?

I'll include some code snippets below, but I'm sure it's not anything particularly original.

Javascript:

```
            function myTimer() {

            var typingTimer;
            var doneTypingInterval = 2000;

               $("#devicename").keyup(function(){
               clearTimeout(typingTimer);
               if ($('#devicename').val()) {
               typingTimer = setTimeout(updateText, doneTypingInterval);
               }



            });

                    function updateText() {

                    var devname = $('#devicename').val();
                    $.get("http://domainname/cgi-bin/ajax.pl", "devicename="+devname,
                            function(response,status,http) {
                                    $('#resultsbox').html(response);

                            }, "text");
                    }

            }
```

HTML

```
<div id="resultsbox">
<table class="devicetable">
 <tr>
    <td class="tablehead">Company Name</td>
    <td class="tablehead">ID</td>
    <td class="tablehead">Status</td>
    <td class="tablehead">Ticket</td>
    <td class="tablehead">Device/Ticket Notes</td>
    <td class="tablehead">Open SR</td>
 </tr>
<tr> lots of stuff </tr>
</div>
```

Perl

```
sub generate_results {
       #DBI stuff, result is formatted and loaded into $result
       print $html->header('text/html;charset=UTF-8');
       print $result;
 }
```

Thank you for an information you can provide.  I'm happy to read on the subject, just not finding anything pertaining to something like this.  Everything I find seems to blank the div, reset a form, or write the next set of results.  Nothing seems to want to go back to the original state.  Before anyone wonders, the reason I don't simply provide a standard search results scenario, instead choosing to pare down from the entire list, is because the database information displays a status that may change from time to time, and the list in it's entirety is used as a type of operational awareness.  That's why I want to go from full list to only results back to full list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the div [inner html](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp) somewhere safe and then restore it.

With plain javascript:

```
// store original html
var originalHtml = div.innerHTML;

// restore it
div.innerHTML = originalHtml;
```

or with jquery like you use it:

```
// store original html
var originalHtml = $('#resultsbox').html();

// restore it
$('#resultsbox').html(originalHtml);
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion.  Any recommendation on how to manage the trigger event?  I am assuming it would fire from the same "onkeyup" that creates the initial results, and an "if" statement would dictate whether or not I go to Perl for new $results, or replace the div with the originalHtml?  I'm certainly open to suggestion about what might be a good method for that trigger.  Thanks!

Comment: looks like updateText() is the most fitting place - if devname is empty you need to restore original html, if not empty - query and set. As for storing the original html you just need to do it once when page loads.  BTW it looks like you're making a one-page application, consider using a proper framework for that (I'm not saying you necessarily should, as I don't really know your app and its purpose, but you should read and think about it).

Comment: Works out great.  Thanks, Ness.  While it is is certainly bigger than one page, I'm still very interested in what you mean by "proper framework".  Would you mind giving a little more detail about your intent there?  My site is rendered by Perl TT, and I'm using some Catalyst stuff for deployment.  Just starting to get involved in the Catalyst stuff.  Is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: Glad it worked :) As for "proper frameworks" you are basically implementing dynamic views yourself (html that changes via ajax instead of page loads) and there are many frameworks out there that do that and more. To name few - angularjs, reactjs, emberjs.. These framework handle all common cases and are well tested, and can be easily integrated with REST apis and other standard server views. Some of them might be overwhelming for beginners but if you are interested you might want to check them out.

Comment: Will do.  In fact, the next chapter in the book I'm currently reading is about ember.js, so that works out well.  Thanks again.  Have a good one.